# What chemicals have been named after Star Wars characters?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

The molecule below is whimsically named Yoda1 because it "uses the force" to open channels in a class of animal proteins known as piezo ion channels (which appear to be part of their pressure sensing nervous systems). See this [*Nat. Commun.* **2018,** *9* (1)](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-018-04405-3) for a description and other links.

[image: yoda1]

This raised the question for me of how many and what other interesting chemicals have been named after Star Wars characters?

Comment: You should be aware that this is an open-ended question, which is not typically within the scope of stack exchange; typically these are closed as too broad.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I'd agree if there were a vast number of *answers* but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: That does not take away the open-endedness of the question itself. If a huge star wars nerd comes along and starts naming newly designed molecules after SW characters/places/things, then this list would have to be amended... but I am neither for nor against closing this question.

Answer (score 8):

I heard about one other Star Wars compound named after a character: Kinobeon A.<sup>[1]</sup>

[image: Kinobeon A]

There is also a supramolecular structure named after a Tie fighter.<sup>[2]</sup>

[image: supramolecular Star Wars Tie Fighter Ship]

Apparently there is also a Yoda1 analogue (note the additional sulfur atom) called Dooku1.<sup>[3]</sup>

[image: Dooku1]

#### References:

1. Kanehira, T.; Takekoshi, S.; Nagata, H.; Matsuzaki, K.; Kambayashi, Y.; Osamura, R. Y.; Homma, T. A novel and potent biological antioxidant, Kinobeon A, from cell culture of safflower. *Life Sci.* **2003,** *74* (1), 87–97 [DOI: 10.1016/j.lfs.2003.06.033](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.lfs.2003.06.033). Mirror: [www.chm.bris.ac.uk](http://www.chm.bris.ac.uk/sillymolecules/kinobeon.pdf)
2. D'souza, F.; Gadde, S.; El-Khouly, M. E.; Zandler, M. E.; Araki, Y.; Ito, O. A supramolecular Star Wars Tie Fighter Ship: electron transfer in a self-assembled triad composed of two zinc naphthalocyanines and a fullerene. *J. Porphyrins Phthalocyanines* **2005,** *09* (10), 698–705 [DOI: 10.1142/S1088424605000812](https://doi.org/10.1142/S1088424605000812).
3. Evans, E. L.; Cuthbertson, K.; Endesh, N.; Rode, B.; Blythe, N. M.; Hyman, A. J.; Hall, S. J.; Gaunt, H. J.; Ludlow, M. J.; Foster, R.; Beech, D. J. Yoda1 analogue (Dooku1) which antagonizes Yoda1-evoked activation of Piezo1 and aortic relaxation. *Br. J. Pharmacol.* **2018,** *175* (10), 1744–1759 [DOI: 10.1111/bph.14188](https://doi.org/10.1111/bph.14188).

Comment: Fascinating. But you should include the structures or some explanation of why the names arose.

Comment: Good point. I have added some images of the structures.

Comment: Please do not include any update/edit statements into your post, the edit history is available for anyone to check, and those statements are confusing for new readers of your post.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Thank you for your feedback. I saw similar update/edit statements in other Stack Exchange posts, so I thought it was the way to do it. Lesson learned. :-)

Comment: I completely understand. Our format is a bit different from the traditional online forum, and probably a bit harder to get used to. Unfortunately it's not always possible to make all posts a better fit so you'll come across these kind of things quite often. These are usually not necessary - just edit the post into what you think is the best version and ignore people who might have already read it. ;)